# wildfly logging duplicate logs

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have got problem with setting wildfly logger.properties i add my own file handler and there is a setting:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MY_FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="test-file.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.mypackage" >
            <level name="DEBUG"/>

            <handlers>
                <handler name="MY_FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

As you see i add MY_FILE handler and then i set com.mypackage to use that handler but i have got three logs in my file why, where is the reason of that situation  :

```
2015-03-24 18:45:05,257 INFO  [com.mypackage.web.controllers.LoginController] (default task-8) ------------------------------
2015-03-24 18:45:05,265 INFO  [com.mypackage.web.controllers.LoginController] (default task-9) ------------------------------
2015-03-24 18:45:05,279 INFO  [com.mypackage.web.controllers.LoginController] (default task-10) ------------------------------
```

My code :

```
 @RequestMapping("login.html")
public String login(final Authentication auth) {

    log.info("-----------------");


    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && auth != null) {

        return "redirect:index.html";
    }

    return "login";
}
```

There is any change that its problem with class loader ?? 
I add breackpoint on log.info, and debug application and there is no change that is a problem that this method was called three time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct to me. I see 3 different threads doing the logging. There's nothing wrong with the configuration.

Comment: I add info about my code its nothing special, simple controller that return site. Maybe the problem is with class loader ?

Comment: No. The method is definitely being invoked 3 times. IIRC the `@RequestMapping` annotation is a Spring annotation. Maybe something in the Spring container hitting it 3 times. It's definitely not a class loader.

Comment: OK so you suggest error with spring configuration ?

Comment: Could be. I really have no idea, but I know it's not an issue with WildFly. WildFly doesn't process the `@RequestMapping` annotation so something else has to be hitting the end point.

Comment: Yee but its not a problem with spring beans. Because our application is combination spring + ejb. So the problem with logs is in all application.

Comment: The problem is solved, there is 2 appender-ref  declaration on the same point and file in log4j.xml configuration.